# "setting with enlargement" behavior in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Could you help me understand the following.

`df1` is a dataframe indexed by date.
`df2` is another dataframe also indexed by date, but `df1` and `df2` only have one date in common, `2018-12-31`.
See the following output:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]}, index = pd.to_datetime(["2018-12-31","2019-12-31","2020-12-31"]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'XX':[700,800]}, index = pd.to_datetime(["2016-12-31","2018-12-31"]))
df1['BB'] = df2['XX']

            A   BB
2018-12-31  1   800.0
2019-12-31  2   NaN
2020-12-31  3   NaN
```

I realize that this works, even though the number of rows is not the same on the left and right hand side of `df1['BB'] = df2['XX']`.

Is this an abbreviation for a more complex expression? Since the result keeps all the rows in df1, but doesn't expand the index to include the rows in df2. Is this operation like a "`left merge`" ("left join")? Will it ever include the union of `df1's` and `df2's` indexes, filling with NaNs appropriately?

I am using pandas version 1.2.5

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html): `df1.join(df2)` or more exactly `df1.join(df2.rename(columns={'XX': 'BB'}))` in this case. However, it is more technically equivalent to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) which is how the Series is scaled up: `df2['XX'].reindex(df1.index).rename('BB')`

Comment: Check out [_reindex_for_setitem](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L10833) where this occurs.

Comment: thank you @HenryEcker that clarifies everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting with enlargement is part of [`__set_item__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L3623) which is called when performing operations like:

```
df['col'] = someSeries
```

In this case the function [`_set_item`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/00e10a5c484ce8f089eaa7d892c3ac91aec6a5f7/pandas/core/frame.py#L3810) is called which is used to "Add series to DataFrame in specified column."

Since DataFrames are indexed, and all of the Series therein contained are also indexed in the same way, the new Series must match the DataFrame index it is being added to.

The [`_sanitize_column`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/00e10a5c484ce8f089eaa7d892c3ac91aec6a5f7/pandas/core/frame.py#L4504) function makes sure the column is compatible. In this case, a [`Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) operation is needed for compatibility (index alignment). This happens in [`_reindex_for_setitem`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/00e10a5c484ce8f089eaa7d892c3ac91aec6a5f7/pandas/core/frame.py#L10833).

---

So in answer to the questions

> "Is this an abbreviation for a more complex expression?"

Yes, the resolved expression is:

```
df1['BB'] = df2['XX'].reindex(df1.index)._values
```

> Is this operation like a "left merge" ("left join")?

Yes. The operation is similar to "left merge" (in effect) as the resulting Series will contain all the keys in `df1` since the Series is reindexed to match `df1`.

In this specific example, [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) produces the *exact* same result:

```
df1 = df1.join(df2.rename(columns={'XX': 'BB'}))
```

> Will it ever include the union of df1's and df2's indexes, filling with NaNs appropriately?

No, it will only ever contain the indexes from the DataFrame it is being added to.